# Bootstrap progress bar timer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, progress-bar

First of, hello, I am using Angular.js, Bootstrap, HTML, and JavaScript (obv these 2).

So, I have the following bootstrap progress bar in my APP:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div id="theBar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%">
        60%
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I'd like it to decrease from 100% to 0% ( each percentage being 1 second), the point would be to make a timer out of it, in which after it reaches zero, the user can no longer perform a specified action. I really have no clue how to do is, or if it is even possible using bootstraps progress bar, Thank you in advance and best regards.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
// Code goes here
var i = 100;

var counterBack = setInterval(function () {
  i--;
  if (i > 0) {
    $('.progress-bar').css('width', i + '%');
  } else {
    clearInterval(counterBack);
  }

}, 1000);
```

```js
// Code goes here
var i = 100;

var counterBack = setInterval(function(){
  i--;
  if (i > 0){
    $('.progress-bar').css('width', i+'%');
  } else {
    clearInterval(counterBack);
  }
  
}, 1000);
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
<h2>Hello window.setInterval!</h2>
    
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%;">
    <span class="sr-only"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

No AngularJS involved in this demo.

Answer (score 1):

shershenUse JavaScript such as

```
document.getElementById("theBar").style.width = "80%";
document.getElementById("theBar").innerHTML = "80%";
```

And your bar will increase to 80%.

You can build a function using this approach to increase by 1% every second.

**Updated solution**

```
<script>
var i = 100;

var counterBack = setInterval(function(){
i--;
if(i>0){
    document.getElementById("theBar").style.width = i+1+"%";
    document.getElementById("theBar").innerHTML = i+1+"%";
} else {
   clearTimeout(counterBack);
}

}, 1000);
</script>
```

The code for loop was borrowed from shershen's answer.

Comment: I probably misread the message slightly, but yes your problem can be solved using this approach.

Comment: I'd have to type that every time, 100 times. And still would have no idea how to change it every second, BUT, it's k, we all make mistakes ;)

Comment: Well I did not say this is a full solution :D But if you like stuff done for you by others you can use same approach as the other guy suggested, so with my code it will look like this. See updated answer.

Comment: Well, I was trying to combine both solutions, but was having problems, because obviously I can't increment the width on `getElementByID` since it's a string. And yes, I got my code done by another person, but now I got this piece of info with me forever, and whenever I need it, I have it with me, and know how to proceed, either to implement it in its raw state or make changes as I need.

Comment: See, this was the idea that I had in mind, pretty much THIS, but didn't knew how to loop it. Anyhow, I just found that the first answer you gave me was wayyy too vast, that's why I complained in the first place.

Comment: No problem, glad you found your solution! ;)

Answer (score 0):

This solution needs ui-bootstrap, and the timer works with seconds:

Html:

```
<uib-progressbar class="progress-striped active" animate="true" value="timer" max="max" type="danger"></uib-progressbar>
```

Angularjs:

```
var app = angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('demoCtrl', function ($scope, $interval) {
$scope.timer = 15;
$scope.max = 15;

var countDown = $interval(function () {
    $scope.timer--;
    if ($scope.timer <= 0) {
        $interval.cancel(countDown);
        //TO DO
    }        
}, 1000);});
```